# Python 3.X Unix Socket Example

Tags: python-3.4

I have been searching the last couple of hours on finding a simple Server / Client Unix Socket Example.  I have found examples for Python 2.X, but I am failing at finding one that works for Python 3.X.

I keep getting TypeErrors.

The example that I have been working with is:

**client.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket
import os
# import os, os.path

print("Connecting...")
if os.path.exists("/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example"):
    client = socket.socket( socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
    client.connect("/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example")
    print("Ready.")
    print("Ctrl-C to quit.")
    print("Sending 'DONE' shuts down the server and quits.")
    while True:
#        try:
            x = input( "> " )
            if "" != x:
            print("SEND:", x)
                client.send( x )
                if "DONE" == x:
                    print("Shutting down.")
                break
#        except KeyboardInterrupt, k:
#            print("Shutting down.")
    client.close()
else:
    print("Couldn't Connect!")
    print("Done")
```

- With the client portion, I was not sure how to get a KeyboardInterupt to work in 3.X, so I killed the Try and Except portions.  Any Advice?
- Also, the syntax from the example I used had multiple modules being loaded from one import
  import os, os.path
  Is this the old way of only loading os.path from os module?

**server.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
import os
# import os, os.path
# import time

if os.path.exists("/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example"):
    os.remove("/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example")

print("Opening socket...")
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server.bind("/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example")

print("Listening...")
while True:
    datagram = server.recv(1024)

    if not datagram:
        break
    else:
        print("-" * 20)
        print(datagram)
        if "DONE" == datagram:
            break
print("-" * 20)
print("Shutting down...")
server.close()
os.remove("/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example")
print("Done")
```

- When I run this I get TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface.
- Does Python 3.4 Unix Sockets only support binary?
- What is the easiest way to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With the help of John Hobbs from www.velvetcache.org, I was able to make the above work in Python 3.4.  Thanks for the help John!

https://gist.github.com/jmhobbs/11276249

Answer (score 2):

To answer the OP's questions explicitly:

1. The "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface" error was caused by attempting to send/receive string-encoded data over a bytes interface.
2. Unix sockets have no knowledge of encodings, they pass raw bytes, and Python 3+ no longer does any magic bytes<->encoded string conversions for you, so in this sense yes, (Python 3(.4)) Unix sockets only support "binary".
3. The easiest way to make it work was as @jmhobbs demonstrated in his above-linked gist: you must .encode() your strings to bytes when client.send()'ing them and .decode() the bytes back to strings when server.recv()'ing them.

Answer (score -5):

One thing you may need to do is replace if os.path.exists("/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example"): with if os.path.exists("/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example") == True:

Comment: It's exactly the same

Comment: Actually it's worse, to rephrase the line explicitly it would be `if os.path.exists("/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example") is True:` whereas the `==` is for matching a variable to a value. As in `if x == "some text string": print(x)`.