# Connection refused when using abstract namespace unix sockets

Tags: python, c, sockets, unix, unix-socket

I have a strange problem with unix socket (US) using so-called abstract namespaces when using Python and "pure" C (Python 3.x but looks like 2.x have the same problem).
"Normal" socket works like a charm. With "abstract" one US my code works only when I'm using same "code platform" (C or Python).

First I thought it has something to do with `memset` / `str(n)cpy` (see [Can not connect to an abstract unix socket in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30818410/5512967)) but imho it's not that case.

Test matrix (srv - server, cli - client):

- srv + cli @ "abstract" unix sock:

  - python + python = OK
  - c + c = OK
- srv + cli @ "normal" unix sock:

  - python + python = OK
  - c + c = OK
- srv + cli @ "normal" unix sock:

  - python + c = OK
  - c + python = OK
- srv + cli @ "abstract" unix sock:

  - python + c = FAIL [cli / strace output: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)]
  - c + python = FAIL [cli / raised exception: socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused]

`/proc/net/unix` / `lsof` or `strace` show nothing unusual:

- working "normal" socket C client:
  `// ...`
  `socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0)        = 3`
  `connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"/var/tmp/sock.tmp"}, 110) = 0`
  `// ...`
- misbehaving "abstract" socket C client:
  `// ...`
  `socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0)        = 3`
  `connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"/var/tmp/sock.tmp"}, 110) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)`
  `// ...`

Python bug or what...?

Gist with code samples for **my test matrix**: https://gist.github.com/soutys/ffbe2e76a86835a9cc6b

**Original** code / samples:

- C servers/clients - based on https://github.com/troydhanson/network/tree/master/unixdomain
- Python servers/clients - based on [Python 3.X Unix Socket Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23282635/5512967)

### Update 2015-11-02

More info about system and compilations:

- host system: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (x64);
- all C test files compiled with `gcc` (example: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o abs_cli abs_cli.c`);
- all programs (both compiled and built-in python) run as non-root user;

Comment: the referenced 'C' client code, does not compile!! Including the original sources.  amongst other things it is missing the header file: `#include <string.h>` for the system functions: `memset()` and `strncpy()`.   Always enable all warnings when compiling, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: Also, the C code in both srv and cli does suffer from exactly the issue described in the linked post. The strncpy will only copy the \0 null, no matter what you give it as n (as long as n > 0). Use memcpy().

Comment: @user3629249 it compiles with gcc on my x64 ubuntu both with `-Wall` and `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`... ok - I added string.h header entries for clarity.

Comment: @thuovila as you may see there's a shift in strncpy:  
`strncpy(&addr.sun_path[1], socket_path, sizeof(addr.sun_path) - 2);`  
which gives proper "offset" in zeros-padded struct.

Comment: I may not see. It is not present in the versions of https://github.com/troydhanson/network/blob/master/unixdomain/srv.c I have looked at at least. Also, that is not a very sensible way to do it. Just use memcpy() if you have nulls in your data.

Comment: @thuovila :D I was talking about **my** code (at gist)...

There's a working solution but it needs to be verified (reviewed?) first by someone from python dev-team.

Answer (score 0):

When binding a UNIX domain socket to an abstract name, the addrlen argument should be sizeof(struct sockaddr_un's sun_family) + number of characters in abstract name + 1. The "+1" is for the null byte in front of the abstract name in sockaddr_un's sun_path. Let's look at an example:

- Server in C:

  ```
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_un addr;
  /* create socket, set addr.sun_family, set addr.sun_path to 
     null byte followed by abstract_name */
  bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr.sun_family) +
       strlen(abstract_name) + 1);
  ```
- Client in Python:

  ```
  client = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, ...)
  client.connect( "\0abstract_name" )
  ```

References:

- **The Linux Programming Interface** by Michael Kerrisk, Example 57-8.
- http://blog.eduardofleury.com/archives/2007/09/13